# How can I use vector with a reference type instance object in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have std::vector with no copyable object (has reference instance) in C++11 ?

```
struct CanNotCopy {
  int& intref_;
  CanNotCopy(int& i) noexcept : intref_(i) {}
  // How do I make move constructor and operator = ?
};

std::vector<CanNotCopy> hoge; // OK
hoge.resize(10); // default constructor required
int j = 123;
hoge[1] = CanNotCopy(j);  // copy constructor required
```

Comment: It is sufficient, if objects can be _moved_. However, the class `CanNotCopy` is neither _copyable_ nor _movable_, so it can not be used as a element type for `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, if you have no default constructor (note that non-movable classes certainly can have a default constructor; however your class doesn't), you have to tell `resize` how to construct the new objects. Unfortunately the only way to do so is to give an object to *copy* from, so you cannot use `resize` with classes which are neither default-constructible nor copy-constructible.

Comment: To clarify, the `CanNotCopy` type is both copy constructible and move constructible. The second problematic line requires the type to be move assignable. Reference members interfere with the assignment operators but not the copy and move constructors. (Not being assignable does prevent the type from being considered either Copyable or Movable though.)

Answer (score 5):

From [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), describing `T`:

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

`CanNotCopy` is not moveable, or copyable, so cannot be used as `T`.

A partial solution is to use [`std::reference_wrapper<CanNotCopy>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) as the element type (which is copyable but not default constructible) which:

> ...is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like std::vector or std::pair) which can not normally hold references.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<CanNotCopy>> hoge;
int j = 19;
CanNotCopy c(j);
hoge.push_back(std::ref(c));
std::cout << hoge[0].get().intref_ << "\n";
```

`resize()` is unavailable with `std::reference_wrapper<CanNotCopy>` because it is not default constructible. However, this solution is fragile as there are lifetime dependencies on the `CanNotCopy` referenced *and* the `int` referenced within the `CanNotCopy` instance, running a risk of dangling references.

A solution is to use [`std::unique_ptr<CanNotCopy>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as the element type (which is moveable and default constructible):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CanNotCopy>> hoge;
hoge.resize(5);
int j = 19;
hoge[1].reset(new CanNotCopy(j));
std::cout << hoge[1]->intref_ << "\n";
```

The lifetime dependency on the `int` reference within `CanNotCopy` still remains though.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward, to allow a `vector<CanNotCopy>`:

```
struct CanNotCopy {
  int& intref_;
  CanNotCopy (CanNotCopy && from) : intref_(from.intref_) { }
};
```

This will of course allow you move objects in and out of the vector, but not to create copies, or create default-constructed elements. I have no idea abut the semantics of the class, in particular I don't know what `intref_` means. You have to initialize it in the default ctor too, so I can't write that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by means of using [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)/[`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional) wrappers. The second requires using of [in-place factories](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html) to achieve desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question that has been very nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801993/1951907): use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).