# std::vector<Foo> when some members of Foo are references

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, move-semantics

I often prefer to use references than pointers whenever possible, it makes the syntax cleaner in my opinion. In this case, I have a class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar & bar) : bar_(bar) {}

private:
    Bar & bar_;
};
```

`operator=()` is implicitely deleted by the compiler for such a class, since once a reference is set, it cannot be changed (I can technically define my own that doesn't change bar_, but this would not be the required behaviour, so I'd rather the compiler complain if I try to assign a foo).

What I need is a `std::vector<Foo> v;`. This is impossible before C++11, since the template parameter must to be CopyAssignable. Indeed, when I call `v.push_back(Foo(bar));`, the compiler complains. But I feel it could be possible since C++11 and Move semantics.

My question is: is there a workaround using C++11 that would make building such a vector possible, or am I stuck in this case and have no way around using pointers instead of references? If there's a workaround, I'd highly appreciate a code snippet since I'm unfamiliar with move semantics.

Comment: I think emplace back is what your looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use vector with a reference type instance object in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954974/how-can-i-use-vector-with-a-reference-type-instance-object-in-c11)

Comment: Does `Foo(const Foo && foo) : bar_(foo.bar_) {}` not solve this?

Comment: I'm sure, depending on how your classes define their constructors, that `push_back` will work fine using implicit move generation. Your example compiles fine for me?

Comment: You need the [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or the `boost::optional`. Both of them have the size of a pointer. `boost::optional< T & >`/`boost::optional< T const & >` have desired semantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voila [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is able to do the job because of perfect forwarding.

```
#include <vector>                                                                  

class Bar{};                                                                       
class Foo                                                                          
{                                                                                  
public:                                                                            
    Foo(Bar & bar) : bar_(bar) {}                                                  

private:                                                                           
    Bar & bar_;                                                                    
};                                                                                 
using namespace std;                                                               
int main() {                                                                       
    vector<Foo> v;                                                                 
    Bar bar;
    v.emplace_back(bar);                                                     
}
```

You can also store a reference by itself in a container with [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) used like`std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v`

Comment: @Boris can you post a full example that doesn't compile because I actually realized for my example push_back compiles too

Comment: @Boris sorry I'll take a look but it might be hard to figure out what's wrong since I don't have that compiler

Comment: You should be passing the arguments for Foo's constructor directly to `emplace_back`, otherwise you're creating an unnecessary temporary object and calling the copy/move constructor.

Comment: @Trillian your talking about the first emplace_back right, I'll prolly just remove it

Comment: @Trillian got rid of it

Comment: @Boris there was nothing wrong with it, it just created an unecessray copy, which could be avoided anyway by moving it

Comment: @aaronman that should be `v.emplace_back(bar)` not `v.emplace_back(Foo(bar))`. `emplace` is meant to take constructor arguments for the type being created, not on object of that type. @Boris - yeah, gcc 4.6 is pretty far back on the c++11 support. 4.8 is much better.

Comment: @Charlie actually either way is fine, depending on what constructors you have, I'll change it to your way for this case

Comment: @Charlie you can pass an object of that type as long as you have the proper constructor for it

Comment: @aaronman true - if you've got copy or move constructors, then it will work because there's a constructor that takes an object of the same type as a  parameter. It's just more idiomatic to do it without the intermediate constructor - that can only make your performance worse, though likely won't hurt too much.

Comment: As an additional note, while none of these would work with gcc 4.6.3, any of `emplace_back(bar)`, `emplace_back(Foo(bar))`, `push_back(Foo(bar))` or even `push_back(bar)` compiles and run as excepted with gcc 4.8.1.

Comment: @Boris good, btw if possible I would just use clang, better error msgs, faster compile times, better c++11 support. I've heard optimized binaries can be slightly slower but I would guess that clang will catch up in that department since they are known to have a more maintainable code base than gcc :)

Comment: Thx for the advice, but I'm fine with gcc so far, and it's the default one supported on Ubuntu (well, I had to manually install the new version in this case, but it's because I have an old version of Ubuntu), so there's no reason to fix smth that's not broken :-P

Answer (score 1):

Use [`v.emplace_back(bar)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `push_back`. It will construct a `Foo` in place in the memory `vector` has allocated for it, thus requiring no copying. Just pass `emplace_back` the arguments to construct a `Foo`.

Comment: +1 for providing the correct syntax, I accepted aaronman for code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

The template parameter of a container doens't have to be CopyAssignable, it depends on what operations you perform on your container, and if you really use operation that requires CopyAssignable or MoveAssignable, you cannot use a reference as you wish (even with move semantic). But if you use only other operations (see standard), it will be fine. Some operations only needed CopyInsertable, MoveInstable and/or EmplaceConstructible.